# firestore function only returns a promise

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase

I've been trying to solve this for ages now and I'm not closer than I was at the start. I starting to think I'm looking in the wrong place, but I have no idea.

simple firebase function:

```
export const fsFetchLesson = async (language: string, id: string) => {
  const docRef = firebaseFirestore
    .collection(`lessons/source_language/${language}`)
    .doc(id)

  try {
    await docRef.get().then((doc) => {
      if (doc.exists) {
        // console.log('doc', doc.data());   //  <-- logs the correct doc
        return doc.data();                   //  <-- returns a promise
      }
      console.log('No such document found');
    });
  } catch (error) {
    console.log('Error finding collection', error);
  }
};
```

I need `fsFetchLesson` to return the value of `doc.data()`, yet the output of this function is a pending promise. Same thing happens if I copy paste the exact `then()` solution from the firebase documentation. Still just returns a pending promise.

---

```
const fsFetchLesson = async (language: string, id: string) => {
  const docRef = firebaseFirestore
    .collection(`lessons/source_language/${language}`)
    .doc(id);

  try {
    await docRef.get().then((doc) => {
      if (doc.exists) {
        // console.log('doc', doc.data());
        return doc.data();
      }
      console.log('No such document found');
    });
  } catch (error) {
    console.log('Error finding collection', error);
  }
};

// ! HERE
const a = async () => {
  const data = await fsFetchLesson('english', 'zlnWzwJ6rhZeKOZXdqIS');
  return data;
};

const b = a();
console.log(b);
// returns promise pending
```

^ drawn out attempt, still just returns a promise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are mixing promises and async/await which often causes confusion. For one, an `async` function *will always return a Promise, no matter what*. That's how `async` functions work. In this case, you end up executing a separate promise chain in the middle of the function without waiting for a result. Try something like this instead:

```
export const fsFetchLesson = async (language: string, id: string) => {
  const docRef = firebaseFirestore
    .collection(`lessons/source_language/${language}`)
    .doc(id);

  try {
    const doc = await docRef.get()
    if (doc.exists) {
      // console.log('doc', doc.data());   //  <-- logs the correct doc
      return doc.data();                   //  <-- returns the data
    }
    console.log('No such document found');
  } catch (error) {
    console.log('Error finding collection', error);
  }
};
```

Comment: copied your solution exactly and it still appears as a pending promise in my React component. I'm starting to wonder if this is some `NextJS` shenanigans.

Comment: nope, nevermind. copied and pasted the logic over to a completely different React project and I'm still getting a promise pending issue.

Comment: Yes, that's the nature of async/await. You will always need to `await` the function or `.then()` to get the result of the promise. If there is a promise *anywhere in the call chain* the whole thing will need to be awaited.